# Authenticating multiple clients using single cert

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate

I have a deployment where there is one server and N number of clients. Generating different certs for all clients is not possible.
So I am thinking of creating a single server cert and single client cert to do cert based authentication.

Using a single client cert will have host name mismatch problem.

Is this approach good enough or I need to think something else?

Comment: Host name verification is something done by the client to authenticate the server. It doesn't make sense to check the host name of a client certificate, with 1 or N client certs.

Answer (score 1):

Host name mismatch can be reported or not reported, this depends on validation mechanism. So if you implement custom validation mechanism, this is not a problem.

However, such scheme is not secure - as the number of clients grows, the probability of the leak of  the private key grows almost exponentially, quickly reaching 1 (leak is inevitable).

So you need to rethink the approach to authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't begin to make sense. You can't authenticate *N* clients without *N* client certificates.

Comment: As suggested above can't we ignore the hostname part?

Comment: Please elaborate why we can't authenticate N clients with 1 certificate if we don't have to differentiate between clients. For me anyone having this cert is good.